# Language and Knowledge skills and the point buy system

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

Do characters which are created with the point buy system still get the free knowledge / language skills as priority system created characters do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, the free knowledge/language skill points are based on your primary attributes, not something you buy separatedly. Since the point-buy alternate system doesnt replace the Core Rulebook ruling, it remains the same.